# jQuery Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I'm getting an "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" with the following code on the .ajax call.  Notice that all of the data is commented out except for the data {} portions of the code.  If I comment the data {} portion of the code it "works".  Meaning it pops up two alerts, the fail and the always alerts.  I have tested this in both Chrome and Firefox although Firefox doesn't give the same error it still fails to work properly.  Any suggestions?

I know there have been several posts about this error but none of the ones I've read seem to have this particular problem.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var submitted = false;

$('.inxAddToCart').on('focusout click', function () {
    if (!submitted) {
        submitted = true;
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        inxVerifyOrderQty();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'GenerateContent.aspx',
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
            //    option: escape('Shopping Cart'),
            //    func: escape('func'),
            //    item: escape($('#inxPartNumber').val()),
            //    weight: escape($('#inxWeight').val()),
            //    id: escape($('#inxCatID').val()),
            //    qty: escape($('#titem_qty').val()),
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            alert('done');
            inxDebug('done...');
        }).fail(function (data) {
            alert('fail');
            inxDebug('fail...');
            inxDebug(data);
        }).always(function (data) {
            alert('always');
            inxDebug('always...')
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no real idea but, it looks like "func: scape(func)" may be recursivelly looking for himself, isnt it?